# Error 13 (Permission Denied) when running open on file I created (iOS)

Tags: ios, file, error-handling

I have a simple program running on iOS (iPad) which opens a file, writes some data, closes the file, and then tries to reopen the file. The strange thing is that the second open sometimes fails with return code -1 and errno 13 (Permission Denied). If I run the code several times it will alternately fail and succeed (the pattern seems random).

Below is the code I am using, can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? The first open always succeeds and the write also always succeeds.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];

result = remove([appFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

int fp = open([appFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
result = write(fp, "abc", 3);
close(fp);

fp = open([appFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], O_RDONLY);
NSLog(@"fp = %i, errno = %i", fp, errno);
close(fp);
```

Comment: Does the first open with `O_RDWR | O_CREAT` really work every time? Can you change that to `if ((fp = open(..)) != -1) { } else { NSLog (errno) }`? Can you output the full filename too?

Comment: Yes, I verified the first open is working consistently. The full filename is: /var/mobile/Applications/AF7710BE-48C4-45F9-B749-E010AED330DE/Documents/file.txt

Comment: From the manpage for open: `The oflag argument may indicate that the file is to be created if it does not exist (by specifying the O_CREAT flag).  In this case, open requires a third argument mode_t mode;`. As you do not specify the 3rd argument, it will use a random value, that's why it fails sometimes. Add a 3rd parameter `0644`, then it will always work.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Feel free to make a full answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

From the manpage for open(2):

```
The oflag argument may indicate that the file is to be created if it does
not exist (by specifying the O_CREAT flag). In this case, open requires a
third argument mode_t mode;
```

As you do not specify the 3rd argument, it will use a random value, that's why it fails sometimes. Add a 3rd parameter 0644, then it will always work.

Answer (score 0):

Open file folder must have executable permissions, so use:

```
chmod 0760 "dir"
```